# How to join strings from array with indexes in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, string, indexing, swiftui

I’m making a todo list app with Swift and I’m trying to implement a share function so people can share their todo lists. I want the message to output as `1. Eat 2. Sleep 3. Game 4. Repeat`

I can’t seem to get it to repeat as it only outputs `0. Eat`

My code:

```swift
ForEach(Array(tasks.enumerated()), id: \.element) { i, element in
    ShareLink(item: "https://www.example.com/", subject: Text("My taskfairy list!"), message: Text(String("\(i). \(element)"))) {
        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up") 
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `tasks` look like?

Comment: You are calling ShareLink once for every element, you probably want to join the strings beforehand and then call ShareLink with the joined string.

Comment: @koen State var tasks = [""] and string items are appended as written in text feilds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a computed property to your view that converts the array of tasks into a string

```
var allTasks: String {
    zip(1...tasks.count, tasks).map { "\($0.0). \($0.1)"}.joined(separator: " ")
}
```

and then use that in your view

```
ShareLink(item: "https://www.example.com/", 
          subject: Text("My taskfairy list!"), 
          message: Text(allTasks)) {
    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up") 
}
```